# Retrieve values from json object

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I have a JSON object that is structrued like the following ...

```
 [{"staffId":4,"forename":"Testf","surname":"Tests","location":"Testl","phoneNumber":"00000000000","email":"Teste"}]
```

Can anyone advise how I would retrieve the keys and values and add to Arrays in JavaScript or JQuery. For Example ...

```
var headings = ["staffId","forename","surname"];
var staff = [["1","Joe","Bloggs"],["2","Stack","Overflow"]];
```

Comment: where is the staff information in your old json?

Comment: In the first example above.

Comment: where is `1` `Joe` `Bloggs` in that first example above?

Comment: ok maybe I wasn't clear enough. So i'd like staff = [["4","Test","Test"]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for one such JSON object it will be

```
var json =  [{"staffId":4,"forename":"Testf","surname":"Tests","location":"Testl","phoneNumber":"00000000000","email":"Teste"}];

var headings = Object.keys(json[0]);
var staff = [];
for ( var key in json[0] )
{
   staff.push( json[0][ key ] );
}
console.log( headings );
console.log( staff );
```

for multiple, you need to iterate them like

```
for ( var counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++ )
{
  var jsonObj = json[ counter ];
  //same code for all json objects as above
}
```

Comment: one more thing ... Do you know how I would add staff into seperate arrays within the staff array? e.g. [[array[5]],[array[5]]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        'staffId': 1,
        'forename': 'Joe',
        'surname': 'Bloggs',
        'location': 'Testl1',
        'phoneNumber': '0770....',
        'email': 'Teste1'
    },
    {
        'staffId': 4,
        'forename': 'Testf',
        'surname': 'Tests',
        'location': 'Testl',
        'phoneNumber': '07702671940',
        'email': 'Teste'
    }
];

var headings = ["staffId","forename","surname"];

var result = data.map(function(item) {
    return headings.map(function(heading) {
        return item[heading];
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

you can map/transform your array using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the Json with jQuery

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
```

The call the values

```
alert(json.name);
```